# jQuery - Bodymovin JSON not loading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, lottie, bodymovin

The `slider` and `shuffle` lottie animations are supposed to run from `0` to `100` and then back to `0` when toggled; like the `box` animation.

However you can see that the `slider` animation disappears in the final frame and the `shuffle` animation seems to only go a part of the way through its animation before it stops.

How do I get the `slider` and `shuffle` animations to run in the same way as the `box` where they run from 0 -> 100 and then back again?

Note that `slider` and `box` have additional code where only one can have the open state at a time.

```js
const anim1 = lottie.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById("box"),
  renderer: "svg",
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  path:
    "https://cdn.statically.io/gist/moofawsaw/b8abeafe008f8b9ef040199c60a15162/raw/296dde84544ed1b41d5acfa303cca21c3ceee70f/lottie_box.json"
});
anim1.setSpeed(5);

const anim2 = lottie.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById("slider"),
  renderer: "svg",
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  path:
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/moofawsaw/de2c253620930f2d582daceebff72665/raw/c5d7f528325aed481e6479da1c6921e62066de0b/lottie_sliders.json"
});
anim2.setSpeed(16);

const anim3 = lottie.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById("shuffle"),
  renderer: "svg",
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  path:
    "https://cdn.statically.io/gist/moofawsaw/d009a2a791b03fbf37bca60de465e29c/raw/a87e77ea3362ba6f42cf65f86f0edbc37cb9f15b/lottie_shuffle.json"
});
anim3.setSpeed(12);

function toggle($el, anim) {
  $el.toggleClass("active");
  const open = $el.hasClass("active");
  $el
    .closest(".button")
    .find(".state")
    .text(open ? "open" : "closed");
  const start = open ? 0 : 100;
  anim.playSegments([start, 100 - start], true);
}

$(".lottie--box").on("click", function () {
  var lottie = $(this).find("#box");
  toggle(lottie, anim1);
  if (lottie.hasClass("active") && $("#slider").hasClass("active"))
    toggle($("#slider"), anim2);
});
$(".lottie--slider").on("click", function () {
  var lottie = $(this).find("#slider");
  toggle(lottie, anim2);
  if (lottie.hasClass("active") && $("#box").hasClass("active"))
    toggle($("#box"), anim1);
});
$(".lottie--shuffle").on("click", function () {
  var lottie = $(this).find("#shuffle");
  toggle(lottie, anim3);
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.button {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 46px;
  max-width: 270px;
  min-width: 270px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4aabf0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.lottie--slider {
  background-color: #756fe4;
}
.lottie--shuffle {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
#slider {
  width: 200px;
}
#box path,
#slider path {
  fill: white;
  stroke: white;
}
#box svg {
  min-height: 32px;
  max-height: 32px;
}
#slider svg {
  max-height: 26px;
}
#shuffle svg {
  max-height: 62px;
}
#shuffle svg,
#box svg,
#slider svg {
  transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.55, 1);
}
#box.active > svg {
  transform: scale(0.9) translatey(3px) !important;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.55, 1);
}
.container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
.state {
  min-width: 90px;
  margin-left: 0.9rem;
}
.lottie--shuffle {
  color: blue
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.6);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.7.0/lottie.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="button lottie--box">
    <div id="box"></div>
    <div class="state">closed</div>
  </div>
  <div class="button lottie--slider">
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <div class="state">closed</div>
  </div>
  <div class="button lottie--shuffle">
    <div id="shuffle"></div>
    <div class="state">closed</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick...
So i created a new function for each button.

study the code snippet below(the javascript code)

```js
const anim1 = lottie.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById("box"),
    renderer: "svg",
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    path:
      "https://cdn.statically.io/gist/moofawsaw/b8abeafe008f8b9ef040199c60a15162/raw/296dde84544ed1b41d5acfa303cca21c3ceee70f/lottie_box.json"
  });
  anim1.setSpeed(5);
  
  const anim2 = lottie.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById("slider"),
    renderer: "svg",
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,

    path:
      "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/moofawsaw/de2c253620930f2d582daceebff72665/raw/c5d7f528325aed481e6479da1c6921e62066de0b/lottie_sliders.json"
  });
  anim2.setSpeed(1);
  
  const anim3 = lottie.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById("shuffle"),
    renderer: "svg",
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    path:
      "https://cdn.statically.io/gist/moofawsaw/d009a2a791b03fbf37bca60de465e29c/raw/a87e77ea3362ba6f42cf65f86f0edbc37cb9f15b/lottie_shuffle.json"
  });
  anim3.setSpeed(12);
  
  function toggle($el, anim) {
    $el.toggleClass("active");
    const open = $el.hasClass("active");
    $el
      .closest(".button")
      .find(".state")
      .text(open ? "open" : "closed");
    const start = open ? 0 : 100;
    anim.playSegments([start, 100 - start], true);
  }

  function toggle_for_shuffler($el, anim) {
    $el.toggleClass("active");
    const open = $el.hasClass("active");
    $el
      .closest(".button")
      .find(".state")
      .text(open ? "open" : "closed");
    const start = open ? 0 : 120;
    anim.playSegments([start, 120 - start], true);
  }
  let slider_direction = 1;

  function toggle_slider($el, anim) {
    $el.toggleClass("active");
    const open = $el.hasClass("active");
    $el
      .closest(".button")
      .find(".state")
      .text(open ? "open" : "closed");
    const direction = open ? slider_direction : -slider_direction;  
    // The so-called “conditional” or “question mark” operator lets us do
    //  that in a shorter and simpler way.
    // The operator is represented by a question mark ?.
    //  Sometimes it’s called “ternary”, because the operator 
    //  has three operands. It is actually the one and only operator
    //   in JavaScript which has that many.
    // let result = condition ? value1 : value2;
    anim.setDirection(direction);
    anim.play();
  }



   $(".lottie--box").on("click", function () {
    var lottie = $(this).find("#box");
    toggle(lottie, anim1);
    if (lottie.hasClass("active") && $("#slider").hasClass("active"))
      toggle_slider($("#slider"), anim2);
  });
  $(".lottie--slider").on("click", function () {

    var lottie = $(this).find("#slider");
    toggle_slider(lottie, anim2);
    if (lottie.hasClass("active") && $("#box").hasClass("active"))
      toggle($("#box"), anim1);
  });
  $(".lottie--shuffle").on("click", function () {
    var lottie = $(this).find("#shuffle");
    toggle_for_shuffler(lottie, anim3);
  });
```

```css
.wrap {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border: 2px solid white;
  }
  .button {
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 46px;
    max-width: 270px;
    min-width: 270px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #4aabf0;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .lottie--slider {
    background-color: #756fe4;
  }
  .lottie--shuffle {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
  #slider {
    width: 200px;
  }
  #box path,
  #slider path {
    fill: white;
    stroke: white;
  }
  #box svg {
    min-height: 32px;
    max-height: 32px;
  }
  #slider svg {
    max-height: 26px;
  }
  #shuffle svg {
    max-height: 62px;
  }
  #shuffle svg,
  #box svg,
  #slider svg {
    transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.55, 1);
  }
  #box.active > svg {
    transform: scale(0.9) translatey(3px) !important;
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.55, 1);
  }
  .container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .state {
    min-width: 90px;
    margin-left: 0.9rem;
  }
  .lottie--shuffle {
    color: blue
  }
  @keyframes pulse {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0.6);
    }
  
    50% {
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
  
    100% {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.6.10/lottie.min.js" integrity="sha256-/56Y/jYu6730zlN8iulnNWn2IcVa4wK/ogwk7n9p2JY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="lottie.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="button lottie--box">
    <div id="box"></div>
    <div class="state">closed</div>
  </div>
  <div class="button lottie--slider">
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <div class="state">closed</div>
  </div>
  <div class="button lottie--shuffle">
    <div id="shuffle"></div>
    <div class="state">closed</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

You seems to use an older version of the library, I just replace it with [`v5.6.10`](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web) and it worked fine, this is the first time I use this library, so I had to use a selector to force the `display:block` for `<g>` tags inside the second button to make sure that we have the icon animation (I'm sure there is a better way to make it work for the second icon).

---

**Note**: I changed `bodymovin.loadAnimation` to `lottie.loadAnimation`, here is a working snippet:

```js
var animData1 = {
  container: document.getElementById("toggle"),
  renderer: "svg",
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  path:
    "https://cdn.statically.io/gist/moofawsaw/b8abeafe008f8b9ef040199c60a15162/raw/296dde84544ed1b41d5acfa303cca21c3ceee70f/lottie_box.json",
};
var animData2 = {
  container: document.getElementById("slider"),
  renderer: "svg",
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false, path:"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/moofawsaw/de2c253620930f2d582daceebff72665/raw/c5d7f528325aed481e6479da1c6921e62066de0b/lottie_sliders.json",
};
var anim1 = lottie.loadAnimation(animData1);
var anim2 = lottie.loadAnimation(animData2);

$("#toggle").on("click", function () {
  anim1.setSpeed(5);
  if ($("#toggle").hasClass("active")) {
    anim1.playSegments([100, 0], true);
    $("#toggle").removeClass("active");
  } else {
    anim1.playSegments([0, 100], true);
    $("#toggle").addClass("active");
  }
});
$("#slider").on("click", function () {
  anim2.setSpeed(5);
  if ($("#slider").hasClass("active")) {
    anim2.playSegments([100, 0], true);
    $("#slider").removeClass("active");
  } else {
    anim2.playSegments([0, 100], true);
    $("#slider").addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
#toggle,
#slider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 46px;
  min-width: 270px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4aabf0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

g[clip-path="url(#__lottie_element_48)"] g {
  display: block !important;
}

#toggle path,
#slider path {
  fill: white;
  stroke: white;
}

#toggle svg,
#slider svg {
  max-height: 32px;
  transition: 100ms;
}

#toggle.active>svg {
  transform: scale(0.9) translate(0px, 2px);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.6.10/lottie.min.js" integrity="sha256-/56Y/jYu6730zlN8iulnNWn2IcVa4wK/ogwk7n9p2JY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="toggle"></div>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Forcing the display disrupts the performance of the animation. As you can see the slider's animation here: https://useanimations.com/

Comment: let me find the alternate to using css

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? The slider animation is disappearing at the final frame

Answer (score 4):

Just change this line

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.6.10/lottie.min.js" integrity="sha256-/56Y/jYu6730zlN8iulnNWn2IcVa4wK/ogwk7n9p2JY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It is  just the json you have does not work with old version of library.

```js
var animData1 = {
  container: document.getElementById("toggle"),
  renderer: "svg",
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  path: "https://cdn.statically.io/gist/moofawsaw/b8abeafe008f8b9ef040199c60a15162/raw/296dde84544ed1b41d5acfa303cca21c3ceee70f/lottie_box.json"
};
var animData2 = {
  container: document.getElementById("slider"),
  renderer: "svg",
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  path: "https://cdn.statically.io/gist/moofawsaw/de2c253620930f2d582daceebff72665/raw/c5d7f528325aed481e6479da1c6921e62066de0b/lottie_sliders.json"
};
var anim1;
var anim2;

anim1 = bodymovin.loadAnimation(animData1);
anim2 = bodymovin.loadAnimation(animData2);

$("#toggle").on("click", function() {
  anim1.setSpeed(5);
  if ($("#toggle").hasClass("active")) {
    anim1.playSegments([100, 0], true);
    $("#toggle").removeClass("active");
  } else {
    anim1.playSegments([0, 100], true);
    $("#toggle").addClass("active");
  }
});
$("#slider").on("click", function() {
  anim2.setSpeed(5);
  if ($("#slider").hasClass("active")) {
    anim2.playSegments([100, 0], true);
    $("#slider").removeClass("active");
  } else {
    anim2.playSegments([0, 100], true);
    $("#slider").addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
g[clip-path="url(#__lottie_element_48)"] g {
  display: block !important;
}
#toggle,
#slider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 46px;
  max-width: 270px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4aabf0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#toggle path,
#slider path {
  fill: white;
  stroke: white;
}

#toggle svg,
#slider svg {
  max-height: 32px;
  transition: 100ms;
}

#toggle.active>svg {
  transform: scale(0.9) translate(0px, 2px);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.6.10/lottie.min.js" integrity="sha256-/56Y/jYu6730zlN8iulnNWn2IcVa4wK/ogwk7n9p2JY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="toggle"></div>
  <div id="slider" class='settings-V2'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does the icon disappear in the final frame?

Comment: css issue as explained by my friend below g[clip-path="url(#__lottie_element_48)"] g {
  display: block !important;
}

Comment: Forcing the display disrupts the animation. You can see the intended animation here: https://useanimations.com/

Comment: the file https://cdn.statically.io/gist/moofawsaw/b8abeafe008f8b9ef040199c60a15162/raw/296dde84544ed1b41d5acfa303cca21c3ceee70f/lottie_box.json  is working good  this file  https://cdn.statically.io/gist/moofawsaw/de2c253620930f2d582daceebff72665/raw/c5d7f528325aed481e6479da1c6921e62066de0b/lottie_sliders.json has some issue

Comment: The CDN used in the question for the slider should have no issues.

Comment: It is not cdn  issue it is JSON issue use same JSON in  both slider and toggle they work great

Comment: check these lottie sliders and dpwnload the son I think that's what you need https://lottiefiles.com/tag/slider

Comment: Thanks for the link but I need that JSON file specifically.  That is why I posted the question as I don't know why the JSON was executing at useanimations.com and not in the snippet.

Comment: were you able to find the solution without using CSS?